# dojo NumberTextBox shows decimal point as ',' instead of '.' only in mexican language chrome browser?

Tags: java, dojo, decimal-point

In dojo NumberTextBox filed the value shows as '2350,00' instead of '2350.00' in mexican language chrome browser only.

In Internet explorer and microsoft edge browsers it shows normally means '.' as decimal seperator. But only in chrome browser the decimal seperator is ','.

below is the code,

```
    <input dojoType="dijit.form.NumberTextBox" maxlength="8" class="rightalign noborder" style="width: 70px;" id="servedfor${status.count}"
                                                            name="corpOrderSrv.txtServedFor"    trim="true" value="${itemsList.servedFor}" constraints="{pattern:'#####.00'}"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in chrome browser console ?

Comment: No errors. Only in data it shows ',' as decimal seperator .

Comment: Is your page translated to Spanish after loading?

Comment: No. Total page is not translated into spanish .